# Change activity when network is disconnected

Tags: java, android, webview

I am building an app in Android Studio with Java that uses WebView to display a site inside the app. I want to switch the app's activity to my no_internet.xml activity whenever the user's internet connection is disconnected, so rather than seeing the default Android disconnection screen, they will see my custom one with a retry button. Here is my code for my activity_main.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" >
    </WebView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the entire MainActivity.java file:

```html
package com.example.packagename;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.loadUrl("websitename.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        if (isInternetOn()){
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed(); //maybe shove option first later
        }
    }

    public boolean isInternetOn() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

How can I switch to this activity (rather than the default no-internet screen) when they don't have an internet connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to check the internet connection using code bellow :

```
  public boolean isInternetOn() {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
  }
```

then add some view in activity bellow the `webview` simulate to this :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/no_internet_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       ////add your no internet button and text here

    </LinearLayout>
```

and finally add this in your `OnCreate()` to check the internet and control the visibility of view

```
    if (isInternetOn()){
        mWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noInternetView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        mWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noInternetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

**Update:**

the full code is :

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        WebView webView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            LinearLayout no_internet_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.no_internet_view);//////this line for define no_internet_view
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webView.loadUrl("websitename.com");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            if (isInternetOn()){
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed(); //maybe shove option first later
            }
        }

        public boolean isInternetOn() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting errors saying my classname for the no internet view is not defined, but I define it with the same exact way. This is how I am calling it: `no_internet_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` which it says is not defined. I define it in the same way on activity_main.xml

Comment: did you declared the Linear layout id in `OnCreate()`

Comment: Yes, right below where I defined my webView.

Comment: can you please provide the code ?

Comment: For what file/files?

Comment: for class that you checking the internet from it

Comment: I added the MainActivity.java file to my question

Comment: I see the `LinearLayout` in not declared `LinearLayout no_internet_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.no_internet_view);`

Comment: for full code please see the **update** on my answer

Comment: Do you recommend I declare it by my webView?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean , you can see my answer , I already updated it with what you need to make it work . try it

Comment: The issue I was seeing is when I followed your code, the app would open and then close itself

Comment: sorry for this ,it's my mistake .i removed some of code to be clear to you, so you can see what i added .i updated my answer again .I included the full code as your class

Comment: Ok, had to import the Linear layout class and context class of course, will run the app and see the result

Comment: here is no context required ,because you check the internet from activity and not a fragment .you just need to change the `context` to `this` ,i already changed it

Comment: It kind of works, but if you are in the app and you disconnect the network you still see the old screen when you click a link. If you are out of the app and you disconnect the network it shows the correct screen...

Comment: in this case you need to Check internet connection continuously by using `service` class ,just do some search on internet and you will find the solution